# which jar file contain org.n52.wps.server.observerpattern.ISubject and how can I download it?

Tags: java, gis

I want to write a `.java` file and import it into 52north wps service.
My code is like this:

```
package org.n52.wps.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.geometry.iso.topograph2D.Coordinate;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.CoordinateSequenceTransformer;
import org.n52.wps.server.AbstractSelfDescribingAlgorithm;
import org.n52.wps.io.data.IData;
import org.n52.wps.io.data.binding.complex.GTVectorDataBinding;


import net.opengis.wps.x100.ProcessDescriptionType;
public class ConvexHullDemo extends AbstractSelfDescribingAlgorithm {

@Override
public Class<?> getInputDataType(String identifier) {
    if (identifier.equalsIgnoreCase("FEATURES")) {
        return GTVectorDataBinding.class;
    }
}

@Override
public Class<?> getOutputDataType(String identifier) {
    if (identifier.equalsIgnoreCase("FEATURE")) {
        return GTVectorDataBinding.class;
    }
}

@Override
public List<String> getInputIdentifiers() {
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("FEATURES");
    return list;
}

@Override
public List<String> getOutputIdentifiers() {
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("polygon");
    return list;
}

@Override
public Map<String, IData> run(Map<String, List<IData>> inputData) 
{
    
    if (inputData == null || !inputData.containsKey("FEATURES")) 
{
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while allocating input parameters");
}
    
List<IData> dataList = inputData.get("FEATURES");

if (dataList == null || dataList.size() != 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while allocating input parameters");
}

IData firstInputData = dataList.get(0);
FeatureCollection featureCollection = ((GTVectorDataBinding) firstInputData).getPayload();
}

FeatureIterator iter = featureCollection.
List<Coordinate> coordinateList = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
int counter = 0;
Geometry unifiedGeometry = null;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = (SimpleFeature) iter.next();
                if (feature.getDefaultGeometry() == null) {
                        throw new NullPointerException("defaultGeometry is null in feature id: "+ feature.getID());
                }
                Geometry geom = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
                Coordinate[] coordinateArray = geom.getCoordinates();
                for(Coordinate coordinate : coordinateArray){
                        coordinateList.add(coordinate);
                }
}

}
```

And full tutorial of this code: [Custom 52north WPS by java Process](https://wiki.52north.org/bin/view/Processing/TutorialCustomJavaProcess).

But this error appeared:

> Multiple markers at this line

> - The hierarchy of the type ConvexHullDemo is inconsistent

> - The type org.n52.wps.server.observerpattern.ISubject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Which jar contains `org.n52.wps.server.observerpattern.ISubject` and how can I download it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read a little bit more before posting your questions because I found the answer to your question on the site you linked:

It says you should have WPS set up which is explained here:
https://wiki.52north.org/bin/view/Processing/52nWebProcessingService